# Extrair resultados com explode de uma coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Inseri vários dados dentro da mesma coluna com o `implode`, agora pretendo extrair os resultados da consulta com o explode de forma a ficar com os dados separados para depois os poder trabalhar.

Tenho o código desta forma, mas não está a retornar nada nos arrays:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$sql = "SELECT arrachar FROM centrodb.marcacaoInfancia";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $result1 = explode(' ', $result);

    echo $result1[0];
    echo $result1[1];
    echo $result1[2];
    echo $result1[3];
    echo $result1[4];
    echo $result1[5];
    echo $result1[6];
    echo $result1[7];
    echo $result1[8];
    echo $result1[9];
    echo $result1[10];
    echo $result1[11];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem de "tratar" esse `$result` para determinar como pretende manipular os dados.

Um método muito utilizado é o `fetch_assoc()` que retorna um array associativo da tabela.

Portanto vamos fazer um loop com o `fetch_assoc()` e ler cada linha da tabela:

```
while ($linha= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result1 = explode(' ', $linha["arrachar"]);
    var_dump($result1);
}
```

Caso só tenha uma linha ou uma query com `limit 1` pode ignorar o `while`.

```
$linha= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$result1 = explode(' ', $linha["arrachar");
var_dump($result1);
```

Outro exemplo fazendo uso do `fetch_array` (array comum, númerico)

```
$linha= mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
$result1 = explode(' ', $linha[0]);
var_dump($result1);
```

Comment: Da forma que exemplificou retorna todos os resutados que existem na tabela, mas sempre seguidos, exemplo:`array(1) { [0]=> string(92) "2018-04-26,Peq_Almoço,14,Almoço,12,Almoço_(Dieta),2,Lanche,14,Jantar,10,Jantar_(Dieta),10" } array(1) { [0]=> string(91) "2018-04-27,Peq_Almoço,15,Almoço,12,Almoço_(Dieta),3,Lanche,15,Jantar,12,Jantar_(Dieta),2" }`. Pretendia ter este resultado separado, para poder montar uma tabela para o utilizador final poder consultar

Comment: Você tem que fazer explode de vírgula

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo assim:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$sql = "SELECT arrachar FROM centrodb.marcacaoInfancia";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = '';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data .= $row["arrachar"].',';
}
$result1 = explode(',', $data);

echo $result1[0];
echo $result1[1];
echo $result1[2];
echo $result1[3];
echo $result1[4];
echo $result1[5];
echo $result1[6];
echo $result1[7];
echo $result1[8];
echo $result1[9];
echo $result1[10];
echo $result1[11];
```

Comment: Assim só retorna a primeira linha da tabela

Comment: eu fiz o seguinte: a variável $data está concatenando todos os resultados da consulta e adicionei mais um separador que no caso foi a vírgula, para que posteriormente pudesse ser utilizada no explode. Tente imprimir o resultado dentro do while pra ver se retorna algo diferente.

Comment: Não fui eu que coloquei o voto negativo. Dentro do while mostra as vezes que existem o echo dentro do while, mas sempre a primeira linha da tabela repetida